# Maven error when attempting to build a zookeeper rpm package

Tags: maven, apache-zookeeper

Trying to build an zookeeper rpm package.
In .spec file have specified:
BuildRequires: python-devel,gcc,make,libtool,autoconf,cppunit-devel,hostname,systemd,maven

But does not seem to like the version of maven used:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M3:enforce (banned-commons-lang) on project parent: A type incompatibility occured while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M3:enforce: org.sonatype.aether.util.DefaultRepositorySystemSession cannot be cast to org.eclipse.aether.RepositorySystemSession

Is there a way I can force it to use a newer maven like https://dlcdn.apache.org/maven/maven-3/3.8.6/binaries/apache-maven-3.8.6-bin.tar.gz
That I have been advised works ok with zookeeper 3.8.0?

Have tried specifying BuildRequires >=3.8.6

But results in this error:

Error: No Package found for maven >= 3.8.6

Any help appreciated - very new to builds.

Comment: You have to upgrade your maven-enforcer-plugin to most recent version (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks khmarbaise, pointed me in the right direction, in the .spec file I added the following to use the latest maven:

Added new source entry for maven repo in package info section:

*Source5: https://dlcdn.apache.org/maven/maven-3/3.8.6/binaries/apache-maven-3.8.6-bin.tar.gz*

*%prep*

*tar xvf %SOURCE5 -C /usr/local/***

*%build*

*/usr/local/apache-maven-3.8.6/bin/mvn -DskipTests package*

Now .rpm files generated as expected.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).